# Transfer custom text on Facebook using like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Here's the thing.
Recently I've tried to add FB like button to some website I'm administrating and that was easy, but now I have a request I don't know how to handle.
The thing is, when you like some website, on your FB wall is posted a link (and some other stuff maybe) to that website, its by default and I know I can change that.

What I need is this, on my page I have a (html)div that is loaded dinamycally with some important data and I need to post that particular data on my FB wall.

I tried using javascript and open graph meta tags but it seems to me that these meta tags cannot be changed dinamycally.

If anyone has an idea how to do this, feedback is more than welcome.

Sincerely,
Milos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue.  This can be done using iframe to integrate FB like button.   Piece of infrormation you need to do this can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).
It shows the FB like button and you can add your url in without having to mess up with meta tags

Answer (score 1):

No, you technically cannot do this. 
When you share a link on Facebook, Facebook servers visits the URL specified on sharing, collents META information and displays those.

However, Javascript runs after content is loaded and on browsers, and I don't think Facebook servers run javascripts before getting META information.

Therefore, even if you change Open graph meta tags dynamically, FB still uses old tags (which is set on initial page load).

You should figure out a way to set content before sending HTML to client.